# I am getting segmentation fault when truncating a file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fileptr;
    char filechar[40];
    int siz;

    printf("Enter file name : ");
    scanf("%s", filechar);
    printf("please enter size");
    scanf("%d", siz);

    fileptr = fopen(filechar, "a+");
    ftruncate(fileno(fileptr), siz);
    fclose(fileptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a program for user choice to create file name and file size 
when I run I am getting segmentation fault error, even if I use `fseek(fileptr, siz, SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: `scanf("%d", siz);` -> `scanf("%d", &siz);`. And you need to check if `fopen` succeeds : `if (fileptr == NULL) {display error message and fail...}`.

Comment: Thanks for that feeling embarassed thinking how i missed that

Comment: @user: silly typos are common place, don't worry. Look at the other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have a segmentation fault because you pass the value of `siz` to `scanf()` instead of its address for conversion specifier `%d`. To avoid such mistakes, you should compile in strct mode: `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

There are other problems:

- you should use the larger type `long` for this purpose.
- you should pass the maximum size for `filechar` and use a larger buffer.
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` and `fopen`.
- you should report runtime errors.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fileptr;
    char filechar[1024];
    long siz;

    printf("Enter file name : ");
    if (scanf("%1023s", filechar) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("please enter size");
    if (scanf("%ld", &siz) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fileptr = fopen(filechar, "a+");
    if (fileptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                filechar, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (ftruncate(fileno(fileptr), siz)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot truncate file %s: %s\n",
                filechar, strerror(errno));
        fclose(fileptr);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fileptr);
    return 0;
}
```